How do you let the user filter a SwiftData model using an @State Date
I can't understand why app doesn't have this in its docs but I am letting the user select a month and show in a list only the records that are from the month the user selected;
   @State private var selectedDate: Date = Date.now

               Button {
                    selectedDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: selectedDate) ?? selectedDate
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                }

And then I try to use it in a predicate:
static var fetchDescriptor: FetchDescriptor<Workout> {
    let date = Date.now
    let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Workout>(
       // predicate: #Predicate { $0.endTime == selectedDate },
        sortBy: [
            .init(\.endTime, order: .reverse)
        ]
    )
    //descriptor.fetchLimit = 6
    return descriptor
}

@Query(fetchDescriptor) private var workouts: [Workout]
but it throws the error Key path cannot refer to static member now. How do you let a user filter their data by data in SWiftUI?

You could put the @Query into a subview and pass the predicate.
